# ffprobe show_entries with an entry name that uses a semicolon

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I'm probing a video file to get some basic information. For example, the following uses the show_entries flag to specify the necessary data.

```
> ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=size,duration:stream=codec_name,bit_rate video.mp4
```

I also need to get the TAG:rotate entry, but this does not working as the semicolon mixes with the syntax of the show_entries flag.

```
> ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=size,duration:stream=codec_name,bit_rate,TAG:rotate output.mp4
No match for section 'rotate'
Failed to set value 'format=size,duration:stream=codec_name,bit_rate,TAG:rotate' for option 'show_entries': Invalid argument
```

Is there a way to fix the syntax? The only other solution is not to specify the individual entries and just get all the data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `stream_tags` for metadata tags stored in the stream:

Some examples and results:

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream_tags=rotate -of csv=p=0 input.mp4
90

ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream_tags=rotate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 input.mp4
TAG:rotate=90

ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream_tags=rotate:format=size,duration:stream=codec_name,bit_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 input.mp4
codec_name=h264
bit_rate=39761
TAG:rotate=90
duration=5.000000
size=27114
```

In addition there is `format_tags` for metadata tags stored in the container (global metadata).

Comment: Is there a schema to reference for `section_entries`?  Tried going around https://www.ffmpeg.org/documentation.html for `ffmpeg`, `ffprobe`, `-all`, and Utilities.  Also `ffprobe "$file" -of json=c=1 -v quiet` does not seem to show all either, nor with the additional option combinations `-show_entries ''` or `-show_entries '*'`, even removing `-v quiet`, and simply trying `-of json` too.. `-print_format json` does not seem to help either, like I had used after `-show_chapters` in another command string..  File exists..

Comment: Found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708373/get-ffmpeg-information-in-friendly-way

`ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams "$file" `

Not sure how much is necessary.